# Using Subquery And Ordering The Value By Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm Trying to Get the date , Discount , Total , Net Total ... ordered by date , the discount is showing the real amount but when I select multiple dates the total will be summed in those dates I've selected and it will be ordered by date

```
DECLARE @pR FLOAT = (SELECT  SUM(CAST(Price AS FLOAT)) AS Price 
                     FROM Orders WHERE isPaid = 1  
                      AND PaidDate BETWEEN '8/17/2015' AND  '8/18/2015' ) ;

SELECT Orders.PaidDate 
     , @pR AS Total 
     ,sum(theorderids.Discount) As Discount
     ,(@pR - sum(theorderids.Discount)) AS [Net Total] 
From 
    (SELECT OrderId, PaidDate 
     FROM Orders 
     WHERE Orders.PaidDate BETWEEN '8/17/2015' AND'8/18/2015' 
     GROUP BY Orders.OrderId, Orders.PaidDate) AS Orders
INNER JOIN theorderids ON Orders.OrderId = theorderids.ID 
GROUP BY Orders.PaidDate ;
```

Example Data :

Row 1
    "PaidDate": "17-08-2015",
    "Total": 7388.0,
    "Discount": 38.0,
    "NetTotal": 7363.0

Row 2
    "PaidDate": "18-08-2015",
    "Total": 7388.0,
    "Discount": 2.0,
    "NetTotal": 7363.0

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  Your query is certainly not the best way to accomplish what you want (the use of the variable `@pR` seems unstable).

Comment: Ok Done I've edit the question

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

```
 SELECT TheOrderids.PaidDate, MAX(Price) AS Total 
        ,sum(theorderids.Discount) As Discount
        ,(MAX(Price) - sum(theorderids.Discount)) AS [Net Total]
From 
    (SELECT PaidDate ,SUM(Price ) AS Price 
     FROM Orders 
         WHERE Orders.PaidDate BETWEEN '8/17/2015' AND'8/19/2015' 
         GROUP BY Orders.PaidDate
    ) AS Orders
INNER JOIN theorderids ON Orders.PaidDate = theorderids.PaidDate 
GROUP BY theorderids.PaidDate 
ORDER BY theorderids.PaidDate ;
```

[image]

Comment: This is giving results , But not accurate at all

Comment: What do you mean by " not accurate at all"? I have added the 'ORDER BY theorderids.PaidDate' clause to sort the paiddate. Now check the results. If you don't get the desired results then give a brief description of what is not accurate.

Comment: I've tried the edit and remains the same .. on 17/8/2015 the total must be 3600 , it's showing me 3985

Comment: try this [SQL FIddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/16b70/1) and then tell me whats wrong with this query.

Comment: @YahyaZakariya you can use real data. insert that data and try this on SQL fiddle.

Comment: I've done that .. Also in your example .. day 17 must be 700 not 800 but it's showing 800 .. check it

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
SELECT Orders.PaidDate 
     , @pR AS Total 
     ,sum(theorderids.Discount) As Discount
     ,(@pR - sum(theorderids.Discount)) AS [Net Total] 
From 
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Orders.PaidDate ) AS Row, OrderId, PaidDate 
     FROM Orders 
     WHERE Orders.PaidDate BETWEEN '8/17/2015' AND'8/18/2015' 
     GROUP BY Orders.OrderId, Orders.PaidDate) AS Orders
INNER JOIN theorderids ON Orders.OrderId = theorderids.ID 
GROUP BY Orders.PaidDate ;
```

Comment: that still giving me same results